# Wordpress Plugin, get HTML post content

Tags: wordpress

I am building a wordpress plugin, that acts when the admin saves a new post.
I need to get the content of  that post and i am retrieving `$_POST['content']` and `$_POST['post_content']`.
The problem here is that i only get the text inside that content, i need the html.

This way, if i was expecting something like `<p>Lorem</p><p>ipsum</p><p>dolor</p>`, I get `Lorem ipsum dolor`.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as @ChrisCarson points out, Wordpress doesn't store paragraph tags in the database by default.

So, what I need to do, is parse the paragraphs myself using:

```
$content = explode(PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL, $this->request['content']);
$htmlcontent = '';
foreach($content as $line){
    $htmlcontent .= '<p>' . str_replace(PHP_EOL, '<br />' , $line) . '</p>';
}
```

thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress doesn't store paragraph tags in the database by default.  Try this...

```
$content = trim(stripslashes($_POST["post_content"]));
$html = apply_filters("the_content", $content);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_content#Alternative_Usage

> If you want to achieve the same output that the_content() returns, use
>   the following code:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
> $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
> ?>
> ```